# How to get column count from a table Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

### I need to get the number of columns from a table

I have tried below queries, but it doesnt work. Blank row is displayed.

```
1) select count(*) from dbc.columns where tablename = 'ABC'
2) select count(*) from dbc.columnsv where tablename = 'ABC'
```

`Help column databasename/tablename` gives the list of column names and all the attributes, but count does not work with HELP command.

Also, is it possible to get the number of column/column count for all the tables in a database - Teradata in a single query

Comment: You probably want: `select tablename, count(*) from dbc.columnsV where databasename = 'mydatabase' group by 1;`

Comment: Thank you..It works...Any idea why select count(*) from dbc.columnsv where tablename = 'ABC' doesnt work. it shows me 0 count

Comment: This might happen when the table name is longer than 30 characters. The legacy views (those without `V`)  truncate to 30 chars instead of returning the actual 128.